# Can I easily make my tuple type synonym an instance of Read?

Tags: haskell

I have a type synonym declared for the tuple of two Ints:

```
type Coordinate = (Int, Int)
```

I'd like to read in Coordinates as part of an IO Action, which boils down to using the read function.  Is there a way to leverage the existing Read instance of Tuples to accomplish this?

Comment: `type` creates a *synonym*, not a new type. Tuples are already a `Read` instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
type Coordinate = (Int, Int)
home = read "(1,2)" :: Coordinate
school = read "(10,4)" :: Coordinate
```

Answer (score 6):

Have you just *tried it*?

The answer is: yes, the tuple instance is used, there's no need to do anything at all yourself because `Coordinate` isn't even a different type – it's just a “hard link” to the same type `(Int,Int)`, with all the same functions and class instances.